# What are the column heading for this "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Mar 28 2013 bash" when I do "ls -l" in the Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ls

I executed the command "ls -l" in the ubuntu terminal, I understand the "ls -l" is the long listing in ubuntu, but I don't understand the columns for example: (This was the first line)

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1   root    root    920788  Mar 28 2013 bash
```

How would I find out the column headings for the above?

Comment: It's likely in the manual http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#What-information-is-listed

Comment: Have a look at [this Unix.SE page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103118)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns are :

- Permissions (owner, group. all)
- Links
- Owner
- Group
- Size in bytes
- Time of last modification
- Name

So "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Mar 28 2013 bash" means:

- user root has permissions rwx (read, write, execute).
- group root has permissions r-x (read and execute).
- Everybody has permissions r-x (read and execute).
- The file has only 1 hard link.
- The owner is root.
- The group is root.
- Size is 920788 bytes.
- Last modified in March 28, 2013.
- The file name is *bash*.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what they are:

1st column is - file type(DIR/Files/symlink) and access details for UGO (User Group Others). its -rwxr-xr-x in your case meaning its a simple file with owner can read/write/execute this file, while group and others can just read and execute the file
2nd column is - it gives the number of links to the file. in your case its 1
3rd Column is - User who owns this file. Its root in your case
4th Column is - Group who owns this file. Its root in your case
5th Column is - Size of the file or Dir
6th Column is - (Timestamp)Date and time of file / DIR modified
7th Column is - File/Directory name